# Hoeffding's lemma for vector valued RV

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

I have a random variable $Z$ taking values in $\mathbb{R}^d$, $E[Z] = 0$ and $||Z|| \in [a,b]$

Can I apply Hoeffding's lemma using the random variable $X = ||Z|| - E[||Z||]$ such that

$$
\mathbf{E} \left[ e^{\lambda (||Z|| - E[||Z||])} \right] = \mathbf{E} \left[ e^{\lambda X} \right] \leq \exp \left( \frac{\lambda^2 (b - a)^2}{8} \right)
$$
since $E[X] = 0$ and $X \in [a,b]$?

If yes, does this argumentation hold if $Z$ takes values in a normed space $(N,||\cdot||_N)$?

Comment: You cannot have $E(X) = 0$, unless $Z$ is identically $0$. Indeed, $X$ is a positive random variables, and a positive random variable with $0$ mean is almost surely equal to 0.

Comment: Thx. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Your $X$ does not satisfy $a \le X \le b$. Nevertheless, it is still bounded from above and below, with different constants, so you can apply Hoeffding's lemma to $X$, since this is a real valued random variable.